# Send javascript variable along with form data and bind it to model

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery, data-binding

I have a simple html page.
It contains a form.
For eg: student information

**Model:**

> public Class Student() 
>   
> {
>   
>      public int Roll_no {get;set}
>        public string Name  {get;set}
>  
>   }

Html also has javascript:

```
<script>

var foo= "1";
var bar = "2";

</script>
```

Controller looks like

```
public ActionResult AjaxCallCOntroller(int foo, int bar, Student stud)
{
.....
......
}
```

Now I need to make ajax call to this controller which will pass this values:

```
       **ajax call:**
var studentform = ("#studentform").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST"
    , url:"appname/AjaxCallCOntroller"
    , dataType:"json",
    , data:{foo:foo,bar:bar,stud:studentform},
    , success:function(){
      //function body
    }
);
```

The problem is that `foo` and `bar` are received by the controller but student object is null.
Student object is recived if its sent alone.
ie: data:studentform

Need help on this.

Comment: I think this should work  `data:{ studentform + "&foo=" +foo+ "&bar=" + bar},`

Comment: `AjaxCallController` expects third param as `Stud` object. Don't know what does it interprets  to when called from php but surely javascript is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var studentform = ("#studentform").serializeArray();
studentForm.push({ name: 'foo', value: foo });
studentForm.push({ name: 'bar', value: bar });
$.ajax({
    type:"POST"
    , url:"appname/AjaxCallCOntroller"
    , dataType:"json"
    , traditional: true
    , data:studentform
    , success:function(){
      //function body
    }
);
```

Comment: It worked. Was trying it for whole day.Thanks a lot Karaxuna.